# Replace or substitute using DAX or Query Editor - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a requirement where I have to loop through each character in a text field

For example:

| Input | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| a#123456; 12341 | 123456;12341 |
| a123456 12341bd | 123456;12341 |
| a2017d 12341ds | 12341 |
| a123456/12341bd | 123456;12341 |
| n/a | null |

Basically I am cleaning my data here:

1. I will remove any charachter that is not a number.
2. A number is only valid if there are a minimum of 5 consecutive numbers.
3. In the Input to differentiate the ID's a space or ";" or ',' or '/' could have been used. Multiple ID's will be present in some cases and not restricted to two.
4. To keep it the same, I will replace all these connectors by ";"

**Note:- My steps may not be right, but my expected output is what I am looking to get from the data.**

How can we do this using DAX or Query Editor in Power BI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll attempt this in two steps.

First, let's remove anything that isn't a number or a separator. We can create a custom column to do this with this formula (assuming your starting column is named `Raw`):

```
Text.Remove([Raw], List.Transform({33..43,60..255}, each Character.FromNumber(_)))
```

This uses the [Windows-1252 character numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but you could just write a big list of characters to remove using the [`Text.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-remove) function.

This custom column now looks like this:

```
Custom
123456; 12341
123456 12341
2017  12341
123456/12341
/
```

From here, the plan is to split it using each separator and filter out strings that are too short.

The [`Text.SplitAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-splitany) function allows us to specify multiple separators. For example, the formula `Text.SplitAny("1;23 4.5-6/ 7:8,9", " ,-./:;")` would return `{"1","23","4","5","6","","7","8","9"}`.

Once we have a list of substrings, we can filter the ones we don't want with [`List.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/list-select) and then concatenate them from a list of substrings into a single string using [`Text.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-combine).

Putting all this together, we have this formula

```
Text.Combine(List.Select(Text.SplitAny([Custom], " ,-./:;"), each Text.Length(_) > 4), ";")
```

You can smash it all into one step if you prefer:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Clean",
      each Text.Combine(
               List.Select(
                   Text.SplitAny(
                       Text.Remove(
                           [Raw],
                           List.Transform(
                               {33..43,60..255},
                               each Character.FromNumber(_)
                           )
                       ),
                       " ,-./:;"
                   ),
                   each Text.Length(_) > 4),
               ";"
           )
       )
```